# Unable to append values to FormData and send form (including image) to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, file-upload, form-data

What could be causing the issue of not being able to append values to FormData and subsequently not being able to send the form (including an image) to the controller, even though I am able to retrieve all current values?

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
   
    function handleFileChange(event) {
      setImage(event.target.files[0]);
     
    }
    console.log(image)
  

    const signup = ev => {
     
      ev.preventDefault()
      const payload = new FormData();
      payload.append('Name', nameRef.current.value);
      payload.append('Email', emailRef.current.value);
      payload.append('password', passwordRef.current.value);
      payload.append('password_confirmation', password_confirmation.current.value);
      payload.append('ville_id', ville_ref.current.value);
      payload.append('profil_picture', image);
      AxiosClients.post('/signup', payload)
      .then(({data}) => {
       
        console.log(data);
      })
```

Comment: Please share your full code. You are using useRef where you should be using useState.

Comment: try to `console.log` those refs current value inside `signup` function. maybe the those values are not what you're expected.

Comment: @I am using useRef to obtain the input values. Without append, I am able to retrieve all of the values as I anticipated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the headers `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

```
AxiosClients.post('/signup', payload, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: Kumar "I can retrieve all values except for the image. Although I see the image detai in the console.log(image) name
: 
"158464602_929723631134013_8632819699083321843_n.jpg"
size
: 
55589
type
: 
"image/jpeg"

Comment: Did u try adding content type? Also log the values you are receiving on the backend

Comment: Mayank Kumar I encountered an issue while trying to retrieve the original file name from the $file variable using the getClientOriginalName() method. Instead, I received an error stating "Call to a member function on null". However, I was able to retrieve other values such as Name or fullname without any issues. Here's the backend code snippet that I used:$file = $request->profil_picture;
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
return response()->json($filename, 200); Did u try adding content type? yes i did